# Great Solomon Eagle!

Tags: meaning

In "The New Jersey Sphinx" in Dr. Thorndyke's Case-Book by R. Austin Freeman, a man found a hat that he was searching for, then said:

> "**Great Solomon Eagle!**" he gasped. "Do you see, doctor? It's THE hat."

I see that it's an exclamation expression, but I didn't meet it before, does it refer to a particular meaning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Google of the phrase doesn't turn up any other results other than the book you are quoting from, so I would have to say **no** - it isn't a common expression. However, it isn't entirely unfamiliar to an English speaker and does have a meaning (sort of).

It's basically a *minced oath*, which is when a word or phrase normally considered vulgar or blasphemous is replaced with something innocuous that may or may not sound a little like the original.

"Great Scott!" is a more recognisable minced oath, a substitute for "Great *God*!", which some people may find blasphemous. The exact origins of this phrase are unknown, and the "Scott" in question could be any number of famous Scotts. The "Solomon Eagle" of your quotation seems to refer to the 17th-century composer [Solomon Eccles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solomon_Eccles).

There is something of a comedic tradition of making minced oaths excessively long and ridiculous, such as "Great Caesar's Ghost!" and "Jesus Joseph And Mary In Tinsel Town!". So the use of a lesser known person such as Solomon Eccles in place of Scott also seems quite humourous to me.

Comment: My London infant school (5-7 years), Mrs Taylor, when frustrated with us, used to exclaim "Christopher Columbus!"